# Why can I not divide these two variables?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, division

I am relatively new to python. I tried to import my csv for 2 stocks. When I run the below code, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Does this mean it is treating price as a string? How can I ensure it is treated as a number when it is imported?

```
 import pandas as pd 

stock1 = pd.read_csv('stock1.csv', parse_dates=['Date', 'Price'])
stock2 = pd.read_csv('stock2.csv', parse_dates=['Date', 'Price'])


for i in (stock1,stock2):
    i['Norm return'] = i['Price'] / i.iloc[0]['Price']
```

Comment: You can't divide strings. You have to convert them to numbers first.

Comment: As the error message says, both variables are strings. You can make them integers or floats by using the int(variable) or float(variable) conversions. For example, `i["Norm return'] = float(i['Price']) / float(i.iloc[0]['Price])`

Comment: @MishaMelnyk When I tried this it said: 

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.read_csv` will try to infer the format but sometimes is not able to. You can give type hints via the `dtype` parameter like so:

```
stock1 = pd.read_csv('stock1.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], dtype={'Price': float})
```

Maybe it is enough to pull it out of `parse_dates` though. By writing  `parse_dates=['Date', 'Price']` you tell pandas to try and make the prices a date.

You might also encounter an error which would be the reason pandas does not read the column as float in the first place. A string like 'NAN' in your .csv could do so. In https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html there is a wealth of further parameters you can set to treat such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to divide string. Try to convert them to numeric type, like float:

```
for i in (stock1,stock2):
    i["Price"] = i["Price"].astype(float)
    i['Norm return'] = i['Price'] / i.iloc[0]['Price']
```

Comment: Why is it loading it as a string in the first place? In the csv, it is a number. I tried what suggested and got this:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: I've updated my solution so if your `price` values don't have any non numeric chars, it should work.

Comment: "Why is it loading it as a string in the first place? In the csv, it is a number. " No; in the CSV, *it is a string*, guaranteed. *Everything* is a string in the CSV. Files on disk just store raw data, which has no type; the file format specifies types, but CSV treats everything as strings. Any further interpretation of those strings depends on whatever is *using* the CSV. In your case, that's your program, and it needs to *have actual code* that examines the *text that represents* numbers, and replaces it with the actual numbers. Such as provided in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have '$' symbol in your price so first, you have to remove '$' from the price.

Comment: I do not have $ in the price. It is just a decimal number.